# .htaccess rewrite rule not working for subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having some problem with my rewrite rule.
I have the below rewrite code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^subcategory/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) child-category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It's working great, however when i add  child-category.php in the sub folder **doctor** and try to access the file it doesn't work.

`http://localhost:8888/community/doctor/subcategory/health` -> Doesn't work
`http://localhost:8888/community/subcategory/health` -> working fine.

It should work in the sub folder as well, can anyone see anything obvious to why its not working?

Comment: The `^` anchors your regex pattern at the start - `^subcategory/...` allows only for paths that _start with_ `subcategory/`. For `subcategory/health` that's the case, for `doctor/subcategory/health` it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself,

Here's the solution:
I copy .htaccess file in the sub folder and it's working perfect, you can apply different rewrite rules for each folder.